# Parsing Scientific Notation in dynamic-expresso

Tags: dynamic-expresso

Just wondering why parsing of scientific notation was not implemented. I was able to add it with a few simple functions using RegularExpressions. The code scrubs the expression string to replace scientific expression values with double strings prior to evaluation.
Ex) 
"SomeVar<=5.5e-3"  becomes: "SomeVar<=0.0055"
"SomeOtherVar>=-9.9E4"  becomes: "SomeOtherVar>=-99000"

I will add it if anyone is interested.

Comment: You are right, for now scientific notation is not supported. I think this is not a question for SO. I suggest to write directly to github, https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso. For sure this can be an interesting feature. A pull request is very appreciated. thanks